# Embed vs oEmbed tags

Tags: discussion

What is the difference between [embed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embed) and [oembed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oembed)?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All oEmbed is embed, but not all embed is oEmbed.

oEmbed refers too pretty specific technology and protocol for enabling easy embeds. But not all embeds are "easy", plenty might involve pasting things like scripts into a content, without easiness of URL-only oEmbed workflow.